# Struggling with a simple SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm pretty bad at SQL and have been having some troubles doing somewhat of a UNIQUE join of two tables. The SQL structure is somewhat abysmal, but I didn't design it.

I have two tables:

**users**

uid, ufn, uln, ue

*Where users id = uid.*

and

**transactions**

uid, unit, address, start_date

Basically in the transactions table, there are multiple entries per uid. What I am looking to do is select `users.ufn, users.uln, users.ue, transactions.unit, transactions.address` based on **ONLY** the newest start_date. Meaning I will only get **ONE** result per uid. Currently I'm getting returns for **ALL** uid entries in the `transactions` table.

I've tried doing some JOINS, LEFT JOINS, and things with MAX, but have been largely unsuccessful.

`SELECT * FROM users JOIN ( SELECT unit, address, start_date FROM transactions GROUP BY uid) as a ON users.tenant_id = a.tenant_id`

Is what I tried among a mix of other things.

Any hint as to the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is the start_date just a date field or is it actually date time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will get you close.  The problem will be if 2 transactions have the same start date for the same user.  But if you don't have that case this should work fine.

```
select u.ufn,
       u.uln,
       u.ue,
       t.unit,
       t.address
from   users u
inner join (
            select uid, 
                   max(start_date) as newest_start_date
            from transactions
            group by uid) x
on u.uid = x.uid
inner join transactions t
on t.start_Date = x.newest_start_date
and t.uid = u.uid
```

Comment: I had to modify this a little bit, but this was just what I needed to get my on the right track. Thanks Bill!

Answer (score 1):

Your example SQL has "tenant_id" but that is not in your tables example?
Are you running this once or 10000 times a day?

Try this:

```
SELECT users.ufn, users.uln, users.ue, transactions.unit, transactions.address 
FROM users join transactions on users.uid = transactions.uid
WHERE transactions.UID, transactions.start_date IN
(SELECT UID, MAX(start_date) FROM TRANSACTIONS GROUP BY UID);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an ANTI JOIN on an inequality

```
select users.ufn,
       users.uln,
       users.ue,
       t.unit,
       t.address
from   users
INNER JOIN transactions t 
ON  t.uid = u.uid
LEFT JOIN transactions t1
ON t.uid = t1.uid
 and t.start_date < t1.start_date

WHERE
      t1.uid is null
```

Because of   `t.start_date < t1.start_date` and    `t1.uid is null` only records that don't have another record with a greater start_date will be selected

As with `MAX()` if two or more transaction have start_dates that tie for a user you will get both

Answer (score 0):

This query could work:

```
SELECT
   u.ufn,
   u.uln,
   u.ue,
   t2.unit,
   t2.address
FROM
    users AS u
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            uid
        ,   MAX(start_date) AS start_date
        FROM
            transactions
        WHERE
            uid = users.uid
    ) AS t1
INNER JOIN
    transaction AS t2 ON t2.uid = t1.uid AND t2.start_date = t1.start_date
```

Temporary tables are also an option (may be faster, you have to try):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
    last_transactions
AS SELECT
    uid
,   MAX(start_date) AS start_date
FROM
    transactions
GROUP BY
    uid
;
SELECT
    u.ufn,
    u.uln,
    u.ue,
    t2.unit,
    t2.address
FROM
    users AS u
INNER JOIN
    last_transactions AS t1 ON t1.uid = u.uid
INNER JOIN
    transaction AS t2 ON t2.uid = t1.uid AND t2.start_date = t1.start_date
```

P.S.: You should definitely consider adding a primary key to the `transactions` table. This would allow for a better join clause between `t1` and `t2`. Also, it would prevent duplicates that may occur when multiple `start_date` occur for the same user.

P.P.S.: wouldn't adding a `last_transaction_start_date` column to the `user` table be wiser?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this would be exactly same syntax in MySQL (most likely it will be), but here is how you would do it in SQL server.

Use a rank() function to determine the latest date.

SELECT x.* , y.*
FROM users as x
JOIN
(SELECT *, RANK() Over (Partition By UID Order By Start_Date DESC) as Rank_ FROM Transactions) as y
ON x.uid = y.uid and y.rank_ = 1

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Nope - no window functions in MySQL.